# Bootstrap Modal button close cannot close if second time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

My modal can close if first time but open modal again and close it cannot.
What wrong with my code. The code below is my code

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Username</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
    public IActionResult CreateUsername()
    {
        Usernames username = new Usernames();
        return PartialView("_AddUsername", username);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your controller code? I think you should use the asynchronous type in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

From you codes, you lost `</div>` at last. If still not working, please try use the codes below from [Modal-components](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#modal-components) of Bootstrap.

```
   <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]